# CentOS 6.6 memory size and lack of GUI installer?

Tags: centos

I just installed CentOS 6.6 on my computer using VirtualBox.

My question is why when I create a virtual machine with 1024MB have a GUI but if I create a virtual machine with 512MB I do not as in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with CentOS 6.x and its installer. You need a minimum of 652MB to get the GUI installer, otherwise it drops back to the text based one. See the release notes:

> The installer needs at least 392MB of memory to work. Text mode will automatically be used if the system has less than 652MB of memory..

I think this requirement is due to the the Python interpreter that is used by CentOS to facilitate the graphical windows requiring the minimum amount of RAM of 652MB of RAM. I vaguely recall reading that in a thread which I cannot dig up now.

#### References

- http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.0